# Why does df.loc not seem to work in a loop (key error)

Tags: python, pandas

Can anyone tell me why df.loc can't seem to work in a loop like so

```
example_data = {
    'ID': [1,2,3,4,5,6],
    'score': [10,20,30,40,50,60]
}
example_data_df = pd.DataFrame(example_data)

for row in example_data_df:
    print(example_data_df.loc[row,'ID'])
```

and is raising the error "KeyError: 'ID'"?

Outside of the loop, this works fine:

```
row = 1
print(example_data_df.loc[row,'ID']
```

I have been trying different version of this such as example_data_df['ID'].loc[row] and tried to see if the problem is with the type of object that is in the columns, but nothing worked.

Thank you in advance!

EDIT: If it plays a role, here is why I think I need to use the loop: I have two dataframes A and B, and need to append certain columns from B to A - however only for those rows where A and B have a matching value in a particular column. B is longer than A, not all rows in A are contained in B. I don't know how this would be possible without looping, that would be another question I might ask separately

Comment: In your own words, where the code says `for row in example_data_df:`, what do you think that will make `row` equal to each time through the loop? (Did you **check that**?) Now, does it make sense to use that result as an index for `.loc`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you check 'row' as each step, you'll notice that iterating directly over a DataFrame yields the **column names**.

You want:

```
for idx, row in example_data_df.iterrows():
    print(example_data_df.loc[idx,'ID'])
```

Or, better:

```
for idx, row in example_data_df.iterrows():
    print(row['ID'])
```

Now, I don't know why you want to iterate manually over the rows, but know that this should be limited to small datasets as it's the least efficient method of working with a DataFrame.

Comment: Thank you, it works! What I'm trying to do is: I have two dataframes A and B, and need to append certain columns from B to A - however only for those rows where A and B have a matching value in a particular column. B is longer than A, not all rows in A are contained in B. I don't know how this would be possible without looping, that would be another question I might ask separately

Comment: Yes better ask a separate question, make sure to provide a reproducible example of the DataFrames